# How to dynamically create jquery object with json data for JustGage

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, justgage

I want to use the justgage to show data from mysql database, so all my object must be created dynamically. 
My request retrieve correctly all the data I want, so what is include in the file getData.php works great.

When I want to loop on this data, it doesn't work, I can't retrieve each row with all the data, it's giving me something like [object Object], [object Object], [object Object],...

Also, I don't know how to use my dynamic data to create my "new JustGage" and then, refresh the data each 5000ms

Is it possible to do what I want?

getData.php

```
$link=connectBD();
$query="SELECT iod.ReadingValue, iod.Timestamp, io.Name AS ioName, io.OrangeAlarmVal, io.RedAlarmVal, r.Name AS radioName
        FROM io_data iod
        JOIN io ON io.ID_IO = iod.ID_IO
        JOIN radio r ON r.IDRadio = io.IDRadio
        WHERE iod.Timestamp = (SELECT MAX(iod2.Timestamp) 
                               FROM io_data iod2 
                               WHERE iod2.ID_IO=iod.ID_IO)";

$table = array();
$table['cols'] = array(
    array('label' => 'ReadingValue', 'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => 'Timestamp', 'type' => 'string'),
    array('label' => 'ioName', 'type' => 'string'),
    array('label' => 'OrangeVal', 'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => 'RedVal', 'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => 'radioName', 'type' => 'string')
);

$result=selectData($link, $query);
$rows = array();
while($r = getRowElement($result)) {
    $temp = array();
    $temp[] = array('rv' => $r['ReadingValue']);
    $temp[] = array('ts' => $r['Timestamp']);
    $temp[] = array('ion' => $r['ioName']);
    $temp[] = array('op' => $r['OrangeVal']);
    $temp[] = array('rp' => $r['RedVal']);
    $temp[] = array('rn' => $r['radioName']);

    $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
}

// populate the table with rows of data
$table['rows'] = $rows;

// encode the table as JSON
$jsonTable = json_encode($table);

// set up header; first two prevent IE from caching queries
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json');

// return the JSON data
echo $jsonTable;
```

other.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    /** Get Data from database **/
    var dataIO=getData();

    $.each(dataIO, function(i, item) {
        alert(item);
    });

    /*** This part should be generate within the loop with the retrieved fields (data between '**')

        var maxGreen=**OrangeVal** - 0.1;
        var minOrange=**OrangeVal**;
        var maxOrange=**RedVal** - 0.1;
        var minRed=**RedVal**;

        **ioNameVal**=new JustGage({
          id:"**ioNameVal**",
          value:**ReadingValue**,
          min:-50,
          max:0,
          title:"ioNameVal",
          decimals: 1, 
          customSectors :[{"lo":-29.4,"hi":maxGreen,"color":"#a9d70b"},
                         {"lo":minOrange,"hi":maxOrange,"color":"#FF6A00"},
                         {"lo":minRed,"hi":0,"color":"#ff0000"}],
          levelColorsGradient: false
        });

// For each JustGage created, I need to setup a automatic reading in the 
// database, so when the data change, the JustGage is refreshed
        setInterval(function(){
            **ioNameVal**.refresh(**ReadingValue**));
        }
        ****/
}

function getData(){
var json = $.ajax({
    url: 'getData.php', 
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false
}).responseText;

data = $.parseJSON(json);

return data;
```

}

**update**: 
Now, I can retrieve my data from the database and generate dynamically all my justgage object. But I'm not sure this is the good way. I need to refresh all my gauge according the new data in the database. Is there another way to do this?

other.js

```
/** Get Data from database **/
    var dataIO=getData(3);

    /*$.each(dataIO.rows, function(i, item) {
        alert(item);
    });*/

    var idIO; var readingValue; var timestamp; var defaultIOType; var ioName; var orangePressure; var redPressure; var radioName;
    var maxGreen; var minOrange; var maxOrange; var minRed;
    var cpt=1;
    $.each(dataIO.rows, function(i, object) {

        $.each(object, function(j, val) {
            // Pour chaque row
            $.each(val, function(k, temp) {
                //alert(k + "=" + temp);
                switch(k){
                    case 'id':
                        idIO=temp;
                    break;
                    case 'rv': // reading value 
                        readingValue=temp;
                        break;
                    case 'ts': // timestamp
                        timestamp=temp;
                        break;
                    case 'iot': // default IO type
                        readingdefaultIOType=temp;
                        break;
                    case 'ion': // IO Name
                        ioName=temp;
                        break;
                    case 'op': // orange pressure
                        orangePressure=temp;
                        if(orangePressure!=null){
                            maxGreen=orangePressure-0.1;
                            minOrange=orangePressure;
                        }
                        else{
                            maxGreen=-22.6;
                            minOrange=-22.5;
                        }
                        break;
                    case 'rp': // red pressure
                        redPressure=temp;
                        if(redPressure!=null){
                            maxOrange=redPressure-0.1;
                            minRed=redPressure;
                        }
                        else{
                            maxOrange=-20.1;
                            minRed=-20;
                        }
                        break;
                    case 'rn': // radio name
                        radioName=temp;
                        break;
                }
            });
            eval('gauge_'+idIO+'= new JustGage({id:idIO,value:readingValue,min:-29.4,max:0,title:ioName,label:"inHg",decimals: 1,customSectors : [{"lo":-29.4,"hi":maxGreen,"color":"#a9d70b"},{"lo":minOrange,"hi":maxOrange,"color":"#FF6A00"},{"lo":minRed,"hi":0,"color":"#ff0000"}],levelColorsGradient: false})');

            /*setInterval(function(){
                eval('gauge_'+idIO).refresh(getDataRefresh(idIO));
                },3000
            );*/            



            cpt++;
        });
    });
    setInterval(function(){

        $.each(dataIO.rows, function(i, object) {

            $.each(object, function(j, val) {
                // Pour chaque row
                $.each(val, function(k, temp) {
                    //alert(k + "=" + temp);
                    switch(k){
                        case 'id':
                            idIO=temp;
                        break;
                    }
                });

                eval('gauge_'+idIO).refresh(getDataRefresh(idIO));
            });
        });
    },30000
    );          

function getData(typeToGet){
    var json = $.ajax({
        url: 'getData.php', // make this url point to the data file
        dataType: 'json',
        type:"POST",
        data:{"typeToGet":typeToGet},
        async: false
    }).responseText;

    // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
    data = $.parseJSON(json);

    return data;
}

function getDataRefresh(id){
    var json = $.ajax({
        url: 'getDataRefresh.php', // make this url point to the data file
        dataType: 'json',
        type:"POST",
        data:{"id":id},
        async: false
    }).responseText;

    // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
    data = $.parseJSON(json);
    return data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You are trying to `alert` items which typecasts arguments into strings. Your item objects do not have a custom `toString()` method, so the default to string value is `[object Object]`.

If you want to inspect what the item looks like, try using the devtools / console. Instead of `alert(item)`, use `console.log(item)` or `console.dir(item)`; then open up your console (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd> in Chrome and Firefox).

2. What you want to do is possible. You will want to read about `setTimeout`. To be honest however, polling the server for data is not a great design .

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I can get the json value now... How do you suggest to do it? I need to update my gauge following the changes recieved in the database (ex: every minute)? I've updated my previous post to write my js code...

Comment: I think you may want to try reading about the [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) function.